# Get list of temporary internet files

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9

```
    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
    var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach (FileInfo f in dInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.ToString()); 
    }
```

This only prints out one file titled "desktop.ini". I know that Temporary Internet Files is a virtual folder. How can I iterate through files in a virtual folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What your accessing with your code is the top level folder. To iterate through all the files you will need to take into account all the sub folders in the Temporary Internet Files.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
        var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        DoStuff(dInfo);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DoStuff(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        foreach (var file in directory.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
        }

        foreach (var subDirectory in directory.GetDirectories())
        {
            DoStuff(subDirectory);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured this out right before seeing this answer by looking at the folder with WINRAR and seeing that the file structure was different than it appeared when I accessed the temporary internet files via internet explorer.